# Re-using variables with regards to csv files in python

Tags: python, csv

This is the code currently:

```
with open("all_countries.txt", "r") as f:
        content = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]


outAC = open('all.csv', 'wb')
writer2 = csv.writer(outAC)
writer2.writerow(['location'])

for values2 in content:
    writer2.writerow([values2])

inAC = open('all.csv', 'rb')

writer2 = csv.writer(outAC)
for rows in csv.reader(inAC):
    if rows:
        writer.writerow(rows)

for rows2 in inAC:
    print rows2





inCSV.close()
outCSV.close()
inAC.close()
outAC.close()
```

The last part with `rows2` doesn't give an output of any kind, it is just white space, the csv file I am using is populated and has been used and worked in the previous for loop. So why am I unable to access it a 2nd time using the same variable of `inAC`I have tried making new `open` and `csv.reader` variables but I still get a whitespace output. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: I would suggest you get into the habit of closing your resources properly - you correctly use a `with` statement for your first resource, but your others aren't closed correctly. I would imagine you have, for this exact reason, a buffering issue.

Comment: Thank you so much, it did seem to be a buffering issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
inAC.seek(0, 0)
```

before the last loop.

Comment: would this be after
inAC = open('all.csv', 'rb') ?

Comment: No, before: for rows2 in inAC: I have edited my answer.

Comment: The output is still white space, even when I try for rows2 in inAC.seek(0,0)

Comment: No, you should put inAC.seek(0,0) on its own line, just before the last for loop...

Comment: Ah yes, there is also an other problem in your code, that is you're using a filereader and a filewriter _at the same time_ _on the same file_. Three solutions: 1) use two files, 2) read, close reader, then write. 3) open file in rw mode